# In Excel, how can I calculate leave days and hours of personnel in the office?

Tags: excel, days, hour

In the office, I need to calculate leave days and leave hours of personnel.

In our country, each employee can use 2.5 leave days each month.

so, I need to calculate his leave days and also leave hours to prevent leaving more than 2.5 days per month.
You can see the example image in the attached file.

[image: **You can see the example file in attachment**.]

Comment: This question is very broad. Please show us some examples, what your current state is, what you have tried yourself.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. Broad questions like these are unlikely to get any good answers.

Answer (score 0):

This question is broad but I guess you are asking for some sort of applying condition/ checks to leave days. You can apply a formula of "IF" with required logic to get the desired results.

Comment: I uploaded an example image